# Proof that sum of beta coefficients in lagged multiple linear regression model equals “long run propensity?”

Tags: regression, lags

I understand the “long run propensity” or the “long run effect” of a change in an independent variable in a lagged multiple linear regression model is computed by summing all beta coefficients in the model.

Is there a way to show this? I am having difficult time understanding why is this the case.

On bottom of page 314 in paper linked below, I think it is being said that the user (me) should “empirically” choose the number of lags in the FDL, thereby establishing the permanent effect on y given a 1-unit change in z as happening over two periods. This begs the question, isn’t this “long run propensity” then arbitrary given we are effectively guessing the number of periods that y is affected given change in z? Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

[https://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/TecnicasEconometricas/WooldridgeCh10-12.pdf](https://www.eco.uc3m.es/%7Ejgonzalo/teaching/TecnicasEconometricas/WooldridgeCh10-12.pdf)

Comment: Could you add (as an edit to the post) a reference or link for that claim?

Comment: Yes, Kjetil. See bottom of page 314 here: https://www.eco.uc3m.es/~jgonzalo/teaching/TecnicasEconometricas/WooldridgeCh10-12.pdf